# AngularJS - ng-option dropdown list not setting ng-model value when False selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-forms

I have a `<select>` element that uses `ng-options` to generate the select list and hopefully set the selected to the value of the `ng-model`. Here is my html:

```
<td style="text-align:center">
    <ng-form name="IsTobaccoForm">
        <select name="Input" required ng-model="dep.IsTobacco" ng-options="item.value as item.text for item in yesNoList"></select>{{dep.IsTobacco}}
        <span class="alert-error" ng-show="IsTobaccoForm.Input.$error.required"><strong>*Required</strong></span>
    </ng-form>
</td>
```

My controller contains the following code:

```
$scope.yesNoList = [{ value: true, text: 'Y' }, { value: false, text: 'N'}];
```

If the `IsTobacco` value of the item is true, the value is set properly and everything is fine. However, if it is false, the required error appears, even though `{{dep.IsTobacco}}` renders as false. The really weird part is that if I change the selected item in the list to true, it works fine, however if I set it to false, a new blank item is added to the list and that blank item is selected.

If it seems like the issues do not lie in the lines posted above, I could gladly post more code.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I also used chrome debugger and saw that when the data was being initiated in Angular, the value of `IsTobacco` was equal to `false`.

**Edit 2:** If anyone viewing this is new to AngularJS, I would definitely recommend reading these 2 articles: [part 1](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/2014/08/designing-html-forms-angularjs-part-1) & [part 2](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/2014/08/angularjs-html-form-design-part-2). They are an overview of AngularJS forms.

Comment: For some reason (possibly related to checkboxes?), a value of `false` gets interpreted as a lack of `ngModel` when used with `required` - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2436. One workaround would be to use the string 'true' and 'false' instead.

Comment: @sh0ber oh man. That is not good haha. Thanks for the info on this. I had been forcing myself to not hack out a workaround assuming it was my lack of angular knowledge that was causing the issue.

Comment: No problem, I didn't realize this myself. It probably doesn't need to be this way, considering that checkboxes can take `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` attributes. But I guess it was either this or enforce the use of non-true and non-false values for those attributes on every checkbox, and this was the better choice.

Comment: Ya, that definitely makes sense. I had not considered the ramifications when using `ng-options` with checkboxes.

Comment: Posted as an answer now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is because a value of `false` gets interpreted as a lack of `ngModel` when used with `required`. As discussed [here](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2436), consider this excerpt from the Angular source:

```
var validator = function(value) {
    if (attr.required && (isEmpty(value) || value === false)) {
        ctrl.$setValidity('required', false);
```

If there is a required attribute and its value is `false`, it does not pass validation. This is probably intentional for the sake of more easily validating required checkboxes, in which case the default value for unchecked is `false`.

It may not need to be this way, considering that checkboxes can take `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` attributes but I guess it was either do this or enforce the use of non-`true` and non-`false` values for those attributes on every checkbox, and this was the better choice.

One workaround would be to use the strings 'true' and 'false' instead.

Comment: sh0ber has already mentioned the use of checkboxes but I feel this should be stressed further. I changed my code to use 'Yes' and 'No', and then realised I was hacking when I needn't. Use checkboxes.